# RegQueryValueEx returns ERROR_SUCCESS but the value read (DWORD) is always 0

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, registry, registrykey

RegQueryValueEx returns ERROR_SUCCESS but the value read (DWORD) is always 0 whereas actually in the registry it is non-zero. Below is the image with highlighted registry key that I am querying.

[image]

Please help to resolve this issue. How do I get the right value. Below is the code snippet used to query the value.

```
HKEY hKey;
DWORD dwVal;
DWORD dwCount = sizeof(DWORD);
CString strPathMPSettings = "SOFTWARE\\Novellus Systems\\Proteus\\" + strGrpName + "\\" +  strUserName + "\\MyProteusSettings";
if(RegOpenKeyEx( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strPathMPSettings, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey ) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    if(RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "USER_SETTINGS", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)&dwVal, &dwCount) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        //Code statements in this section is executed.
    }
}
```

Comment: what is hkey for RegQueryValueEx()?

Comment: Complete path of registry ?

Comment: You are probably just seeing the [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/registry-redirector) doing what it was designed to do.

Comment: @santoshdhanawade Edit the code snippet to add the code executed where hKey is populated.

Comment: With your code getting a correct value. Make sure you are having registry path.

Comment: HKEY hKey;
 DWORD dwVal;
 DWORD dwCount = sizeof(DWORD);
 //Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Novellus Systems\Proteus\MyGroup\MyUser\MyProteusSettings
 CString strGrpName = "MyGroup";
 CString strUserName = "MyUser";
 CString strPathMPSettings = "SOFTWARE\\Novellus Systems\\Proteus\\" + strGrpName + "\\" + strUserName + "\\MyProteusSettings";
 if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strPathMPSettings, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &hKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
 {
  if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, "USER_SETTINGS", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)&dwVal, &dwCount) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {

 }

Comment: @santoshdhanawade Yes, the registry entry is present the path that I am querying. Any other help?